# Javascript Listening all Tags

Tags: javascript, onclick, listener, event-listener

how i can click listening all span Tags? The task it so resolve it without frameworks

```
    var spancontainer = document.all.tags('span');
    spancontainer.onclick = function() {
        alert("hi");
    }
[...]
    <span>Hello</span><span>World</span>
```

in jQuery it would like:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage *event bubbling*. Attach an event handler to the root and listen to `click` events:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE specials
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE specials

    if(target.nodeName === "SPAN") {
        alert('hi');
    }
};
```

Now, this will not work if there are other elements inside a `span` and you want to capture the `click` events inside `span`s too. In this case, you have to traverse the DOM:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE specials
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE specials

    while(target.nodeName !== "SPAN" && target !== null) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if(target) {
        alert('hi');
    }
};
```

Comment: That would be equivalent to jQuery's `live` method, which he's not using in his example.

Comment: @Matthew: So? The question is how to listen to clicks on `span` tags. `$("span").click` is *one* example how to do this. There are several ways to achieve the effect.

Comment: There are two different effects.  1. Listeners on all the spans that currently exist.  2. Listeners on all the spans that exist now or in the future.  Based on his `.click` example, it looks like he wants the former.  Your code implements the latter.

Comment: @Matthew: I actually don't expect that the OP choose the jQuery example that carefully. I could also argue that he meant  `document.all.tags('span')` to return some live `spancontainer` that magically applies the `click` handler to every element existing now and in the future. And in any way, better have two different approaches than three times the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
 for(var i=spans.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        alert("hi");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can write `for(var i=spans.length-1; i>=0; i--)` as `for(var i=spans.length; i--; )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var click_alert = function() {
    alert("hi");
};
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
  spans[i].addEventListener("click", click_alert, false);
}
```

You can write a wrapper that uses either addEventListener or attachEvent for broader compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
  // ...
}
```